# Escaping angle brackets if entry point is between tags?

Tags: xss

So I'm trying to evade a filter that escapes `<` and `>`.

I read that it's possible if the XSS gets injected **inside** a tag, but in my case, it gets injected between `<span></span>`.

Are there any methods that I should know about?

Answer (score 1):

If your input gets correctly encoded and rendered between these `<span>` tags consistently, there seems little to go on in regard to XSS.

This sounds like the proper way of rendering user input, apart from rejecting special characters in user input at all.